# Load unity web game on click

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, emscripten

So, my page is all in the same .php file, including my 2d unity web game. That makes the browser freeze 3/5 seconds while the game starts loading, even though the game isn't at the beginning of the page.

I didn't want to put the game on another page since I would like my page to be 100% scrolling. Could the canvas/game be loaded onclick (that way the page would freeze only when waiting for the game to start)?

```
<canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="600%" width="935%"></canvas>
                    <br>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                      var Module = {
                        TOTAL_MEMORY: 536870912,
                        errorhandler: null,         // arguments: err, url, line. This function must return 'true' if the error is handled, otherwise 'false'
                        compatibilitycheck: null,
                        dataUrl: "game/Release/pop.data",
                        codeUrl: "game/Release/pop.js",
                        memUrl: "game/Release/pop.mem",

                      };
                    </script>
                    <script src="game/Release/UnityLoader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Set the `async` attribute on the loader script so it happens in the background. I believe the latest version of emscripten does that for you when you compile if you use a shell file. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Async_scripts